# Is there any joke exist in Man's words?

Tags: meaning, jokes

> Oskar: Trade goods, that's the only currency that'll be worth anything
> in the ghetto. Things have changed, my friend. Did I call this
> meeting? You told Mr. Stern you wanted to speak to me. I'm here. I've
> made you a fair offer.
>
> Man: **Fair would be a percentage in the company**.
>
> (Oskar laughs)

Is there any joke exist in Man's words?

Source: Schindler's List (1993)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this isn't a joke. The man speaking to Schindler is a potential investor in Schindler's enamelware company. Schindler has offered him a fixed amount of goods in exchange for the "investment." The investor doesn't think this offer is fair, and is saying that he would rather receive a percentage stake in (i.e., partial ownership of) the company. Schindler refuses. His laugh is not a reaction to humor, but an expression that he finds the notion ridiculous.